# Printing doubly linked list in C goes into infinite loop

Tags: c, struct, infinite-loop, doubly-linked-list

Im trying to learn doubly linked lists. I used the following to print:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
}node;

typedef struct List{
    node *head; 
}list;

node * createNode(int data) {
    node * newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

_Bool isEmpty(const list *L)
{
    if (L->head == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

_Bool insert(list *L, node *N) {
    if(isEmpty(L)) { 
        L->head = N;
    }
    else{
        L->head->prev = N; 
        N->next = L->head; 
        L->head = N; 
    }
    if (L->head==N)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void _print(list *L){
    node *temp=L->head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    list *L1=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));

    node *N1=createNode(3);
    node *N2=createNode(1);
    node *N3=createNode(5);

    insert(L1, N3);
    insert(L1, N2);
    insert(L1, N1);
    _print(L1);

}
```

for reference my list struct only contains a pointer "head" and my node struct contains next, prev and data.

It prints the correct data but goes into infinite loop.
What is the reason ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your code (once header files and a missing function were added) works fine for me. Please verify it still fails for you. If it does, maybe the problem is in your missing function/macro `isEmpty()`.

Comment: When you `malloc()` the `list` struct in `main()`, you haven't set its members to NULL. So, the chances are, the list will not seem to be empty, even when it is... Best to use `calloc()` instead.

Comment: @yourdad I edited your question because the answer should not be a part of the question. Instead if nobody posts an answer you can post one yourself with the solution you have and accept it. This time I added an answer myself, with some more info. You can consider to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this line in `main`:

```
list *L1=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

Allocates memory for the `list`, but **does not initialize it**.

Without initialization the value of `L1->head` can be anything.
And if it happens to be different than `0` (i.e. `NULL`), `insert` will interpret it as pointing to a valid `node` (which it isn't).

The result is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (**UB**), which means anything can happen. It might seem to work, it can crash, or get into an infinite loop etc.

In order to fix it, you need to initialize the `list` pointed by `L1`.
You can do it at least in 2 ways:

1. Replace the call to `malloc` with [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), which also zeroes the allocated memory:

   ```
   list* L1 = (list*)calloc(sizeof(list), 1);
   ```
2. Add an explicit initialization after the `malloc`:

   ```
   list* L1 = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
   L1->head = NULL;     /*  <--- initialization */
   ```

   You can also add a function for encapsulating the initialization.